# How to return ChildProcess of spawn to other file?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have uses case like run a process. i need to seperate implementation when to call exit code for this process in other file. ex, application run ping process. in specific event from application can kill process.

the problem is cant return ping instance. undefined.

ping.js

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

class Ping {
    flags:  string[];

    constructor(flags: string[]) {
        this.flags = [...flags]
    }

    run() {
        const ping = spawn('ping', this.flags);

        ping.on('spawn', () => {
            return ping
        })
    }
}

export = Ping
```

application.js

```
const Ping = require('ping.js');

const duration = 5000;
const end_time = Date.now() + duration;
const flags = ['-t', 'stackoverflow.com'];
const ping = new Ping(flags)
const pingProcess = ping.run();

pingProcess.stdout.on('data', chunk => {
    console.log(chunk.toString())
})

while(true) {
  const current_time = Date.now();

  if (current_time > end_time) {
    pingProcess.kill()
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return the child process right after spawning it:

```
class Ping {
    flags:  string[];

    constructor(flags: string[]) {
        this.flags = [...flags]
    }

    run() {
        const ping = spawn('ping', this.flags);

        ping.on('error', () => {
            /* error handling logic */
        })

        return ping
    }
}
```

Comment: but i need all things like error implementation inside that ping class. can u explain why it cant place it into variabel? and return later? then the purpose return only to call kill later inside other class. and with this way. i get some glitch. the output not in async. it hold it for 5 seconds and return all.

Comment: @imagesck You can store it in the variable and listen for errors inside the ping class, I have updated the answer. Please take a look

Comment: i think a bit understand now the problem of undefined outside class. its like inside `application` the speed of sync faster than event spawn generate. sometime async terminology make a puzzle.  thx man

Comment: @imagesck The problem with the original approach is that ping is returned from inside the callback, this is the reason why it never reaches the `application` module. You are welcome